# Set 3d plot linewidth in matplotlib 2.x

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using a newer version of matplotlib and the argument that sets the linewidth was removed. They seem to have changed it so I set it in Collections object, but I can't find a way of doing this.

I tried their [example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html) with a different linewidth:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=10, antialiased=False)

# Customize the z axis.
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

But as the figure shows, it doesn't add lines to my surface.

What is the new method for setting linewidths?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linewidth can of course only take effect if there is actually a line to be shown. So one would need to specify the color of the lines to show in order to see them.

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap="RdYlGn", linewidth=2, edgecolor="limegreen")
```